# Enumitem and nested lists behaviour

Tags: lists, enumitem, nesting

I have a problem with `enumitem` package and nested lists. I'm cloning `description` basic list (naming it `notacion`). As you can see in MWE below, when are same type lists, there's no problem, and every level definition works correctly but, when type differs, the second
level settings are not taken.

If you compile the example below, when definition works, list items are in normal font, but when not, list items appears in boldface. (`\normalfont` is a manual setting for second level).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{layouts}

\newlength{\margenbasico}
\setlength{\margenbasico}{1cm}
\setlength{\leftskip}{\margenbasico}

\setlength{\parskip}{4pt} % Separación vertical entre párrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Elimina la sangría de primera línea

\setlist[1]{labelindent=\margenbasico,leftmargin=*,align=left} % Global initial settings for all lists

\newlist{notacion}{description}{2} % Cloning description list

\setlist[notacion]{style=nextline, noitemsep,align=left}

\setlist[notacion,1]{%
  labelindent=\margenbasico,%
  leftmargin=35mm,% \margenbasico+25mm
} %

\setlist[notacion,2]{leftmargin=25mm,font=\normalfont}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\level}{\the\@listdepth}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}

If both lists are same type, second level nested list works correctly:

\begin{notacion}
\item [level] \level
\item [leftmargin] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\leftmargin}
\item [labelindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelindent}
\item [labelwidth] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelwidth}
\item [labelsep] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelsep}
\item [itemindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\itemindent}
  \begin{notacion}
  \item [level] \level
  \item [leftmargin] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\leftmargin}
  \item [labelindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelindent}
  \item [labelwidth] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelwidth}
  \item [labelsep] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelsep}
  \item [itemindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\itemindent}
  \end{notacion}
\end{notacion}

\begin{enumerate}
\item But if list type differ (in this case, into a \texttt{enumerate}
  environment), the second level settings are not taken, even if list
  depth seems be correct: level \level
  \begin{notacion}
  \item [level] \level
  \item [leftmargin] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\leftmargin}
  \item [labelindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelindent}
  \item [labelwidth] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelwidth}
  \item [labelsep] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelsep}
  \item [itemindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\itemindent}
\end{notacion}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item Neither in \texttt{itemize} lists (level \level)
  \begin{notacion}
  \item [level] \level
  \item [leftmargin] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\leftmargin}
  \item [labelindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelindent}
  \item [labelwidth] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelwidth}
  \item [labelsep] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\labelsep}
  \item [itemindent] \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\itemindent}
  \end{notacion}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

An this gives:

[image: enumiten nested list not working]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance